# Export tables from different schemas using DBMS_DATAPUMP api

Tags: database, database-administration, plsqldeveloper, datapump

I have a requirement to export tables from different schemas using DBMS_DATAPUMP api.
Below script is getting failed after exporting 0.5 GB data with below errors:

```
ORA-39126: Worker unexpected fatal error in KUPW$WORKER.FETCH_XML_OBJECTS [JOB:"MySchama3"]
ORA-10260: limit size () of the PGA heap set by event 10261 exceeded
ORA-10260: limit size (1048576) of the PGA heap set by event 10261 exceeded
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 95
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPW$WORKER", line 11252
```

Script:

```
   h1 := dbms_datapump.open (operation => 'EXPORT', job_mode => 'SCHEMA', job_name => exportJobName); 
dbms_datapump.set_parallel(handle => h1, degree => 15); 
dbms_datapump.add_file(handle => h1, filename => exportLogFile, directory => exportLogDir, filetype => 3); 
dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle => h1, name => 'KEEP_MASTER', value => 0); 
dbms_datapump.metadata_filter(handle => h1, name => 'SCHEMA_LIST', value => q'|'MySchema1','MySchema2','MySchema3'|');
dbms_datapump.metadata_filter(handle => h1, name => 'NAME_EXPR', value => q'|in ('Table1','Table2','Table3') |', object_path => 'TABLE');
dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle => h1, name => 'ESTIMATE', value => 'BLOCKS'); 
dbms_datapump.add_file(handle => h1, filename => exportJobName || '_EXPDAT_' || to_char(systimestamp,'dd-mm-yyyy_hh24-mi-ss-FF') || '_%U.DMP', directory => exportStageDir, filetype => 1); 
dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle => h1, name => 'INCLUDE_METADATA', value => 1); 
dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle => h1, name => 'DATA_ACCESS_METHOD', value => 'AUTOMATIC'); 
dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle => h1, name => 'COMPRESSION', value => 'ALL');
dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle => h1, name => 'ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM', value => 'AES256');
dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle => h1, name => 'ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD', value => exportEncryptionPwd);
dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle => h1, name => 'FLASHBACK_SCN', value => flashbackSCN);
dbms_datapump.Start_job(h1);
dbms_datapump.WAIT_FOR_JOB(h1,job_state);
dbms_datapump.Detach(h1); 
exception
    WHEN others THEN
        raise_application_error(-20001,'An error was encountered - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please supply the database version and patch level? Also, it could be beneficial with details on the memory allocation (SGA/PGA). Have you tried to allocate more PGA?

Regards,
Daniel

Comment: Hi Daniel,
My database version is 12.1.0.2.0. I didn't try to allocate more memory to PGA.
Regards, Amar

Comment: What about the patch level of the database? Really, it would also help with information about the memory allocation in the database (SGA/PGA).
But my first try would be to ensure that the database can use more PGA.

Comment: Patch level seems "Patch  20415564     : applied on Wed Jun 24 16:01:15 PDT 2015
Unique Patch ID:  18617752". I didn't find proper content to increase PGA memory, Could you please share the steps to do so.

Comment: You should look at the value for PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET.